# How can I deploy my zend framework 2 application to AWS elastic beanstalk?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, zend-framework2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I understand how to do a basic deployment on AWS elastic beanstalk, but one of the things I'm trying to figure out is how to deploy a Zend Framework 2 application. Because Zend Framework 2 apps depend on Apache running with mod_rewrite, how can I configure my elastic beanstalk to also ensure that Apache is executing with mod_rewrite?

Edit: I'm going to add to this question. I'm not even sure mod_rewrite is an issue anymore. I simply can't even deploy the zend framework 2 skeleton app on elastic beanstalk. I have no problem deploying a single simple PHP file, but deploying an actual zend framework 2 app is a no go. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay this was solved with some help in the #zftalk IRC. I was never successful in uploading using the AWS beanstalk web interface, so instead I used the AWS eb tool and the AWSDevTools.

The best bet is to go into the root of your project. I followed the linux instructions here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/GettingStarted.GetSetup-devtools.html

Then moved on to the deploy instructions here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP.sdlc.html

This still didn't work. So, I went to the web interface of my environment on elastic beanstalk and had to edit the configuration so that the document root in the container pointed to /public. Following this, the server was returning a 500, so I looked in the logs and saw it was having problems with the framework itself. On my local copy I made sure composer had installed everything, I removed the git ignore files from vendor and then committed the project. I pushed out the project with git aws.push again and this worked.

Comment: Hi user602525, how did this pan out?  Would you say that AWS is a viable solution for a production ZF2 app?  What about as a best test environment?

Comment: Yes, AWS has been really great. Since this post, I have deployed several production apps at my job using ZF2 and AWS. My only complaint really would be that PHP is a resource hog, perhaps PHP with ZF2 is a resource hog. I've deployed several Java applications as well, larger than the ZF2 apps I've deployed, the Java apps are running at a fraction of the resource consumption of the PHP apps I've put together. This is important simply because I can get more out of the aws micro instances with Java than I can with PHP. Other than that it has been great.

Comment: Inspired by this success story, I went straight to the document root configuration (Configuration > Software Configuration [click the gear icon] > Container Options: Document root) and entered "/public".  My app began working immediately.